# Как вывести функцию triangle_area, которая принимает длины сторон треугольника и возвращает содержимое треугольника?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как написать функцию `triangle_area`, которая принимает длины сторон треугольника и возвращает содержимое треугольника?

Если указанные длины не могут быть длинами сторон треугольника (не удовлетворяют условиям треугольных неравенств `(a + b > c; a + c > b; b + c > a); (S =√s(s − a)(s − b)(s − c); s = a + b + c/2))` нужно использовать `ValueError`

Вид должен быть следующий:

```
def triangle_area(a: float, b: float, c: float) -> float:
    
>>> round(triangle_area(3, 4, 5), 6)
    
6.0
   
>>> round(triangle_area(5.4, 5.2, 5.3), 6)

12.154663

>>> round(triangle_area(3, 4, 8), 6)

 Traceback (most recent call last):

...

ValueError: Violating triangle inequality

>>> round(triangle_area(3, 2, 1), 6)

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

ValueError: Violating triangle inequality

>>> round(triangle_area(1.5, 2, 0.3), 6)

Traceback (most recent call last):

...
    
ValueError: Violating triangle inequality

'''

raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: вы на каком языке пишете? что такое "содержимое треугольника" :)?

Answer (score 0):

для удобства проверки `a, b, c` лучше отсортировать по возрастанию - легче сравнивать:

```
    (a, b, c) = sorted([a, b, c])
```

если треугольник не может быть построен с такими сторонами - надо выкидывать исключение, например так:

```
    if a + b <= c:
        raise ValueError
```

корень можно вычислить как `math.sqrt()`, так и через возведения в степень `**0.5`, в первом случае потребуется подключить библиотеку

```
    import math
```

с остальным вы должны справиться сами

**P.S.**

в формуле вычисления полупериода у вас ошибка, сами подумайте какая